# How to show an alert when less than 5 words is entered in textbox

Tags: javascript

How can I show an alert when user enters less than the limit into a textbox in vanilla Javascript.

Comment: When do you want to show the alert? I.e: when the user presses Enter?

Comment: Please add any code that you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum and minimum values in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761852/maximum-and-minimum-values-in-a-textbox)

Comment: show your current code

Comment: do you want that function onBlur basically it will be easy for us to answer your question if you can put some code in Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this through

```html
<input type="text" onblur="if (this.value.length < 5){alert('Your alert'); }" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input')
// alerts at 6 characters
if (input.value.length > 5) {
  alert('Your alert');
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```