# How make show message after input value in textbox?

Tags: textbox

How to make a textbox show a message after a value of more than 255 has been input? For example, show a message: "cannot input a value of more than 255".

Comment: Edited question for grammar. Please also tag your question with the language you are using, e.g. Javascript or Java.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, Use Min and Max attributes to set range of values for input type number.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="255">
```

For external references use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761852/maximum-and-minimum-values-in-a-textbox?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to restrict textbox field with size 255. It depends which one you like

1. Set textbox property `maxLength` to 255
   that is `textbox1.maxLength=255`. When you use this, `textbox1` will accept only first 255 characters, after 255, all are ignored
2. Use ontext_changed event of `textbox1`.
   Implement `textbox1_textchanged` event so that it will check size of text entered in the textbox. If `size>255` then show error msg on label.
3. Or you can use `asp:customvalidator` control. You have to implement method for custom validator in the code which will perform same task described in option 2.

Try n let me know which one fir in your scenario. All the best.